# MoveIt RobotState initialisation

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the MoveIt tutorial for the [kinematic part](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/kinematics/src/doc/kinematic_model_tutorial.html), the sample code does the following to get the robot joint position:

```
robot_model_loader::RobotModelLoader robot_model_loader("robot_description");
robot_model::RobotModelPtr kinematic_model = robot_model_loader.getModel();
ROS_INFO("Model frame: %s", kinematic_model->getModelFrame().c_str());
robot_state::RobotStatePtr kinematic_state(new robot_state::RobotState(kinematic_model));
kinematic_state->setToDefaultValues();
const robot_state::JointModelGroup *joint_model_group = kinematic_model->getJointModelGroup("right_arm");
const std::vector<std::string> &joint_names = joint_model_group->getVariableNames();
std::vector<double> joint_values;
kinematic_state->copyJointGroupPositions(joint_model_group, joint_values);
```

The full code is available from [link](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials/blob/kinetic-devel/doc/pr2_tutorials/kinematics/src/kinematic_model_tutorial.cpp).
However, this doesn't give the current robot joint position. If I print out the position using `RobotState::printStateInfo`, the position array is always the same no matter how the robot joint positions are.
I also tried `RobotState::update(true)`, but it is the same.

I wonder if the robot state requires any initialisation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274697/moveit-robotstate-initialisation/) by [linshenzhen](https://answers.ros.org/users/20946/linshenzhen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `"robot_description"` param is just the description of the robot universally (it's loaded from the URDF). The robot model/state does not update automatically, so you're going to be getting back the default joint positions every time because you're just setting it to the default positions. You need to feed in the joint state using `kinematic_state->setVariablePositions(...)`. How you get the joint positions is going to be dependent on your application, but it sounds like you're probably doing a conventional setup where you may be publishing to `"joint_states"`, so you should subscribe to that topic, read the positions in and feed it to the model. The model won't do it for you automatically.

It's a good thing the state doesn't update automatically because it allows us to do things like setting the state to a hypothetical target and testing for things like collisions before actually moving there.

---

Originally posted by [rivertam](https://answers.ros.org/users/32472/rivertam/) with karma: 56 on 2017-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2